# UNIX get 5 minutes ago transaction from JSON SED/AWK

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

I've this particular log in my application

```
{"timestamp":"2020-10-30T20:30:29.722+08:00","status_category":"SUCCESS","status_name":"SUCCESS","delta":36,"sub_calls":[{"operation":"serviceDao.searchDealerByDealerCode","start":1604061029722,"stop":1604061029733,"delta":11},
{"timestamp":"2020-10-30T20:30:29.978+08:00","status_category":"SUCCESS","status_name":"SUCCESS","delta":44,"sub_calls":[{"operation":"serviceDao.searchDealerByDealerCode","start":1604061029978,"stop":1604061029979,"delta":1},
{"timestamp":"2020-10-30T20:30:30.327+08:00","status_category":"SUCCESS","status_name":"SUCCESS","delta":25,"sub_calls":[{"operation":"serviceDao.searchDealerByDealerCode","start":1604061030327,"stop":1604061030328,"delta":1},
{"timestamp":"2020-10-30T20:30:30.397+08:00","status_category":"SUCCESS","status_name":"SUCCESS","delta":51,"sub_calls":[{"operation":"serviceDao.searchDealerByDealerCode","start":1604061030397,"stop":1604061030398,"delta":1},
{"timestamp":"2020-10-30T20:30:30.531+08:00","status_category":"SUCCESS","status_name":"SUCCESS","delta":58,"sub_calls":[{"operation":"serviceDao.searchDealerByDealerCode","start":1604061030531,"stop":1604061030532,"delta":1},
{"timestamp":"2020-10-30T20:30:30.721+08:00","status_category":"SUCCESS","status_name":"SUCCESS","delta":45,"sub_calls":[{"operation":"serviceDao.searchDealerByDealerCode","start":1604061030721,"stop":1604061030722,"delta":1},
```

The objective is to extract the previous 5 minutes log , get the count of success and count of failure
And maybe expect the output to be like

```
Success: 5
Failure : 5
```

I've already have the recipe to get the previous 5 minutes

```
awk -v d1="$(date --date="-5 min" "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N+08:00")" -v d2="$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N+08:00")" '$0 > d1 && $0 < d2 || $0 ~ d2'  /infile/2020103020.jsn
```

But now the challenge is I am having tough time extracting the json using grep.

I even tried

```
sed -E 's/\},\s*\{/\},\n\{/g' /infile/2020103020.jsn | grep  '"timestamp":^C

grep -Po '"timestamp":"\K[^"]*' /infile/2020103020.jsn"
```

I need some enlighten

Comment: You are using regex to parse JSON data, which should be better handled using a JSON parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you status and timestamp:

```
sed -n 's/.*"timestamp":"\([^"]*\)".*"status_category":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1 \2/p' /infile/2020103020.jsn
```

**Output**:

```
2020-10-30T20:30:29.722+08:00 SUCCESS
2020-10-30T20:30:29.978+08:00 SUCCESS
2020-10-30T20:30:30.327+08:00 SUCCESS
2020-10-30T20:30:30.397+08:00 SUCCESS
2020-10-30T20:30:30.531+08:00 SUCCESS
2020-10-30T20:30:30.721+08:00 SUCCESS
2020-10-30T20:30:30.721+08:00 SUCCESS
```

Maybe you can consider some approximation, like read the last 100 lines of the file and ignore the timestamps:

```
tail -100 /infile/2020103020.jsn | \
   sed -n 's/.*"status_category":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'| \
   sort | uniq -c
```